# Get Changeset and all it's changes on TFS using c#

Tags: c#, tfs

I am trying to get a specific changeset by it's changesetid. It is working. The problem is I can't get the files affected by that changeset.

```
Changeset changeset = GetChangeset(new Uri("tfs path"), 10918);

foreach (var w in changeset.Changes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type:" + w.ChangeType);
    Console.WriteLine("Comment:" + changeset.Comment);
    Console.WriteLine("Date:" + changeset.CreationDate);

    foreach (var y in changeset.WorkItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:" + y.Title + y.Type);
    }
}

private static Changeset GetChangeset(Uri serveruri, int changesetid)
{
    var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serveruri);
    var svc = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
    var changeset = svc.GetChangeset(changesetid);

    return changeset;
}
```

The above code is working. I can get the changeset as an object and display the `ChangeType`, `CreationDate` and `Comment` but I can't get the items associated with the change. For example, I edited the `Program.cs`. So it should be visible under that changeset.

Any suggestion would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are already iterating over the Changes in your code. The affected File is in the `Item` property of the `Change` type.

in your case: `w.Item.ServerItem` --> This is the Serverpath of the File like `'$/A/B/C.txt'`

You can download it by using `w.Item.DownloadFile(@"C:\local.txt")`