# Create App to download Changeset in TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

Im not sure if this is even possible but I am looking to be able to create an app (VB or C#) that will essentially replicate the behaviour of the 'View history' of a selected TFS Project. I will want to be able to browse the Changeset, select one and download the solution into a specified location.

I have not had a chance to take a proper look yet, but I assume it is straight forward to get the ChangeSet history from the SQL database, but I am not sure where to look next to be able to download the associated solution/project. Is it something similar to Filestream?

If anyone has covered this in the past, I would love to hear about how you got the project files.

Comment: Do not query the TFS database directly. Use the API. You can find it on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I wasnt aware of the API... that could make things easier. Do you know if there is a mthod for downloading solution files for a given changeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code (I assume you are using TFVC version control):

```
using System; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace API {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string vsuri = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(vsuri));
            tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
            VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
            Workspace ws = vcs.CreateWorkspace("NewWorkSpace");
            ws.Map("$/ProjectName","C:\\LocationPath");
            int changesetversiontoget = 111;
            ChangesetVersionSpec cvs = new ChangesetVersionSpec(changesetversiontoget);
            ws.Get(cvs,GetOptions.GetAll);
        }
    } }
```

The code will create a work space and then get all the files with a specified version like you get a version from Team Explorer\Source Control.

Comment: That looks great! I will give it a go shortly...! Just a quick question... what becomes of the newly created Workspace? Does it exist in TFS... Can I just use an existing Workspace? Or does it just exist temporarily for the duration of the process?

Comment: @CJH It exists in your local machine. Yes, you can use existing one.

Comment: Brill, thanks again Eddie! That gives me something string to work on there! I am guessing if I run the above code twice I might get an error when trying to create a workspace of name "NewWorkSpace" if it has run already? I guess I just do a check to see if it already exists?!

Comment: @CJH Yes, you need to add code to check if the workspace already exist. If it already exist, you can just the exist one, if not, then create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Daniel mentioned, the best way to achieve what you need is through TFS API.

You can follow below links:

[Using TFS API - how to get previous version of a file given a Changeset](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62d8794b-aa14-48f8-9840-9aa4a9c6f69f/using-tfs-api-how-to-get-previous-version-of-a-file-given-a-changeset?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

[Get Changeset and all it's changes on TFS using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545756/get-changeset-and-all-its-changes-on-tfs-using-c-sharp)

If you want to download solution files for a given changeset, this could be achieved through web portal, detailed steps please check below link:
[Download code of a specific changeset in TFVC](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2014/08/20/download-code-of-a-specific-changeset-in-tfvc/)

Comment: This is all good stuff! I have looked at the second link and that all looks good. However this is only looking at the changes on the Change Set. What I need is to get the entire solution as of that Changeset... The same as getting a selected version from Source Control History. The third link seems to be heading down that route however I want to be able to do this entirely in Code-Behind. Are you aware of any examples going this next step? Thanks again for your response! Patrick!