# TFS: List all unique files in all changesets and filter by file type and changeset date

Tags: tfs

I use the following command to list all files from all changesets.  However I want to list only none duplicated files and also filter for certain file types.  How to do that?

```
C:\Windows\system32>tf history /server:http://10.10.30.160:8080/tfs "$/Dev" /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed >C:\History.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **can't be achieved** by a simply [History command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/history-command).

You need to use TFS API to get what you want. First list the files and type , create date from a specific Changeset ID. Then sort the info as your wish.

Here's some example C# code that will select the file names of all edited, added and deleted files:

```
Uri serverUri = new Uri("http://mytfsserver:8080/");
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(serverUri);
tpc.EnsureAuthenticated();
VersionControlServer vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var changeset = vcs.GetChangeset(changesetId);
var changedFiles = from change in changeset.Changes where
       (  (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Edit) == ChangeType.Edit
       || (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Add) == ChangeType.Add
       || (change.ChangeType & ChangeType.Delete) == ChangeType.Delete)
     select change.Item.ServerItem;
```

Another example for your reference: [Get Changeset and all it's changes on TFS using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545756/get-changeset-and-all-its-changes-on-tfs-using-c-sharp)